# how to get a word inside a text html and underline it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a text inside an HTML tag `<p>text</p>`, then I have a `<form>` and a `<input type="text">` inside and a submit.

The goal of the exercise: when I write characters in the input then I click on button (submit), or any other word, or not a complete word, or (,.!!),it has to be underlined with the red color in the text  the space has not to be underlined  .here s my code below :example I write "Anyone" then I submit, I mean the first word in the text , all the words "anyone" have to be underlined in red.

```js
var x = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
var splt = x.split(/\W+/);
console.log(splt);

var inpt=document.getElementById('input').value;
console.log(inpt);

var lent = splt.length;
console.log(lent);

var myArray =[" "];

for(  i = 0; i < splt.length ; i++ ){
  myArray.push(splt[i]);
}

console.log(myArray);

for(var j=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
  for(var k=0;k<myArray[i].length;k++){
    if((myArray[j]==splt)){

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">
      <form class="form-group" action="index.html" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="" value="" id ="input" onkeyup="find()" placeholder="cerca">
        <button class ="Btn btn-danger" type="button" name="button">search</button>
      </form>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <p class="text-justify" id = "text">Anyone who reads Old and Middle English literary texts will be familiar with the mid-brown volumes of the EETS, with the symbol of Alfred's jewel embossed on the front cover. Most of the works attributed to King Alfred or to Aelfric, along with some of those by bishop Wulfstan and much anonymous prose and verse from the pre-Conquest period, are to be found within the Society's three series; all of the surviving medieval drama, most of the Middle English romances, much religious and secular prose and verse including the English works of John Gower, Thomas Hoccleve and most of Caxton's prints all find their place in the publications. Without EETS editions, study of medieval English texts would hardly be possible.</p>
      <p class="text-justify" id = "text">As its name states, EETS was begun as a 'club', and it retains certain features of that even now. It has no physical location, or even office, no paid staff or editors, but books in the Original Series are published in the first place to satisfy subscriptions paid by individuals or institutions. This means that there is need for a regular sequence of new editions, normally one or two per year; achieving that sequence can pose problems for the Editorial Secretary, who may have too few or too many texts ready for publication at any one time. Details on a separate sheet explain how individual (but not institutional) members can choose to take certain back volumes in place of the newly published volumes against their subscriptions. On the same sheet are given details about the very advantageous discount available to individual members on all back numbers. In 1970 a Supplementary Series was begun, a series which only appears occasionally (it currently has 24 volumes within it); some of these are new editions of texts earlier appearing in the main series. Again these volumes are available at publication and later at a substantial discount to members. All these advantages can only be obtained through the Membership Secretary (the books are sent by post); they are not available through bookshops, and such bookstores as carry EETS books have only a very limited selection of the many published.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question title should explain what you're trying to achieve, not how much time you've spent on the task.

Comment: Phrase your title as a question, otherwise people are going to get upset about it and downvote it, which I doubt you want

Comment: Based on the description, I can't tell what you are asking. Please try to rephrase the question and provide an example of what you would like it to do.

Comment: i m going to explain the topic again , i have a html page , containing a text , and search barre with a button , when i write something on the search barre , and i click on submit , the caracters or the words that i wrote , have the be underlined in the text with the red.

Comment: You can find the text you want to underline & wrap it with <u> tag & in the CSS, you can define the color for this underline  as 
text-decoration-color: #FF0000;

Comment: i have to write the program in javascript

Comment: You can totally accomplish such thing with javascript. Just get the content & search for the text you want to underline then wrap the <u> tag around it.
After finishing the decoration, just push the innerHTML back to the <p> element

Answer (score 1):

```js
 function highLightText(){
         var characters = $('#text');
            var pageText = characters.text().replace("<span>","").replace("</span>");
            var searchedText = $('#input').val();
            var theRegEx = new RegExp("("+searchedText+")", "igm");   
            var newText = pageText.replace(theRegEx ,"<span>$1</span>");
            characters.html(newText);
         }
```

```css
#text span
         {
         text-decoration: underline;
         text-decoration-color: red;
         }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>SEARCH</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5">
               <input type="text" name="" value="" id ="input" onkeyup="find()" placeholder="cerca">
               <button class ="Btn btn-danger" type="button" name="button" onclick="highLightText()">search</button>
               <h1>hello</h1>
               <p class="text-justify" id = "text">
                  Anyone who reads Old and Middle English literary texts will be familiar with the mid-brown volumes of the EETS, with the symbol of Alfred's jewel embossed on the front cover. Most of the works attributed to King Alfred or to Aelfric, along with some of those by bishop Wulfstan and much anonymous prose and verse from the pre-Conquest period, are to be found within the Society's three series; all of the surviving medieval drama, most of the Middle English romances, much religious and secular prose and verse including the English works of John Gower, Thomas Hoccleve and most of Caxton's prints all find their place in the publications. Without EETS editions, study of medieval English texts would hardly be possible.
                  As its name states, EETS was begun as a 'club', and it retains certain features of that even now. It has no physical location, or even office, no paid staff or editors, but books in the Original Series are published in the first place to satisfy subscriptions paid by individuals or institutions. This means that there is need for a regular sequence of new editions, normally one or two per year; achieving that sequence can pose problems for the Editorial Secretary, who may have too few or too many texts ready for publication at any one time. Details on a separate sheet explain how individual (but not institutional) members can choose to take certain back volumes in place of the newly published volumes against their subscriptions. On the same sheet are given details about the very advantageous discount available to individual members on all back numbers. In 1970 a Supplementary Series was begun, a series which only appears occasionally (it currently has 24 volumes within it); some of these are new editions of texts earlier appearing in the main series. Again these volumes are available at publication and later at a substantial discount to members. All these advantages can only be obtained through the Membership Secretary (the books are sent by post); they are not available through bookshops, and such bookstores as carry EETS books have only a very limited selection of the many published.
               </p>
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: you are using `jQuery`. please write it in plain JS. The question does not mention using jquery or any other library.

Answer (score 0):

Alright! I tried in Vanilla JS. Have a look https://codepen.io/navdeepsingh/pen/bLjqyy``

```js
const search = document.querySelector('#search');
const wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
const wrapperText = wrapper.innerHTML;
let newText = '';
search.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  const regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'g');
  if (this.value.length > 3) {
    if (wrapperText.includes(this.value)) {
       newText = wrapperText.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
       wrapper.innerHTML = newText;
    } 
  } else {
      const hlElems = document.querySelectorAll(".hl");
      hlElems.forEach(el => {
        el.classList.remove('hl');
      });
  }
});
```

```css
.hl {
background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="search" name="search" autofocus>
<div id="wrapper">
   <p> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
  </p>
  <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
</div>
```